# Static files are not being served due to connection issues between the client and the backend in a MERN stack app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, axios, mern

I'm trying to deploy a MERN stack application to a DigitalOcean droplet. My backend is running on an Nginx server and is successfully connected to a MongoDB atlas instance. I have used FileZilla to serve my static files, and the files are successfully served on the routes that I have no request to the server. But on the routes with requests to the server (to GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE records from MongoDB), the pages load for some milliseconds, and then everything disappears due to errors related to not being able to fetch data from API.
Since the backend is running and connected to MongoDB, I think the URL that I'm passing to the Axios might not be correct.
I had defined a proxy value in the frontend package.json as bellow:

```
"proxy": "HTTP://localhost:5000"
```

and I was making the requests as bellow:

```
axios.get('/api/members')
```

It was working fine on my local machine. However, I read somewhere on a stackoverflow thread that the proxy only takes effect in development mode, not on the production mode. So I removed the proxy from package.json file and changed the axios requests to:

```
axios.get('[IP_to_the_droplet]/members']
```

which I'm not sure is correct, and I think is not, because the routes with HTTP requests on my frontend still don't work. Do you think that the problem is related to the HTTP requests? Do you have any idea how should I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'd usually need a reverse proxy server to map localhost:5000 to the IP of the droplet. You can set up a reverse proxy pretty easly in Nginx. Here's how you do it.

You would start the app with a deamon to broadcast on localhost:5000 and this would be your Nginx configuration

```
. . .
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Detailed steps are here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server